# Rename jQuery/$ - Without noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How I can rename jQuery library to use some other identifier then jQuery/$ ?**

Why? :

Im injecting a external .js file to a website (no server access), where is a old and modified version of jquery running. I need to load new version with a browser extension, but the problem is its conflict with existing one.

**How can I prevent this?**

I tried already noconflict etc. , its renaming the first/old version from the site and not the newer version.

Im using CJS for chrome (extension).

thanks

Comment: If noConflict is renaming the first version, then you are doing so before you include your newer version.  If you include your newer version second, and then do the noConflict, it will restore the older version to the $ namespace.  You can also pass in `true` to the noConflict method and it will restore the `window.jQuery` to the older version as well.

Comment: Still not working, I thinks its because of the CJS Extension for chrome. I put 2 External js file, first jQuery.js then custom.js - In custom js I do noConflict and its show me version of old one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use  Immediately invoked function expression - short IIFE you can avoid conflicts and set the jQuery sign to whatever you want.
Like this:

```
(function(J, w, d){
  J(d).ready(function(){
    J('.selector').addClass(someClass);
    J('.selector').removeClass(someClass);
  });

  J.on('click', () => alert('You clicked me!'));

  w.location.href = 

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Comment: This works because you're creating a closure around your code. This is how JS modules work. It's a good concept to learn. It's great for not polluting your global scope with vars. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: I dont understand this, how this code is related to jQuery?

Comment: It is because if you write your Jquery code in a IIFE it will not intefere with other code on you site. The article that @mccambridge linked is very usefull in understanding Closures.

Comment: @SG52 jQuery is just JavaScript. Understanding how JS works means you'll understand how jQuery works. Wrapping your code in an immediately invoking function means you can pass `jQuery` as a param in place of `J` above. So when you refer to `J` inside the function, you're actually referring to `jQuery`.